# Is there any research about a function with changing "period" like sin(1/x)?

Tags: periodic-functions, almost-periodic-functions, quasiperiodic-function

I'm encountering a function with a "changing period". It has some sense of period but not exactly. For example: f(x) = cos(1/x). Generally, it has the form of f(x + g(x)) = f(x). I cannot find any information about it. Is there any research about this kind of functions? Thanks!

Comment: I guess these can be transformed to regular periodic functions..

Comment: @Berci I cannot, because it is a signal with a constant sampling rate. It will be ununiform for example if I print it with a 1/x axis.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp

Comment: See also [frequency modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation).

Comment: Perhaps [quasiperiodic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiperiodic_function) or [almost periodic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function)?

Answer (score 2):

I second the "chirp" answer. **Chirp** is the derivative of frequency, just as acceleration is the derivative of velocity and velocity of position. Namely, if we have a periodic function $f_P$ and chirp $c(t)$, then

$$y(t) := f_P\left(t\int_{a}^{t} c(t')\ dt'\right)$$

chirps with that chirp.

The name is pretty good: think about what $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ must *sound* like (freakie, huh?) - suppose say the "interesting bit" plays for 1 second. It would have to first sound like nothing, then once it rises to a frequency your ear can hear would start low, then VERY fast go way up in pitch to past where you could hear it again, so it would have a very short "wooeeeEEEEEP!" at the beginning, and then after you cross 0, it would come back down (after *infinite* frequency which, of course, is not possible physically, but also fortunately is not relevant to your ears) making a "PEEEeeeoow!" sound - so all-total you'd get a real short "woeEEEP-PEEEeow!" sound, almost like a birdie chirping - even more if you played a few in succession at slightly randomized close intervals.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function

Comment: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jmath/2021/5536018/